# How is a default culture selected locally - (and why not when running on Azure)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core

I'm building then running my asp.net CORE site in visual studio, and I get my localised resources loading as soon as the site launches, set to the default i.e the English.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("sv-SE"),
                new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
                new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
            };

            // Explicitly state numbers/dates etc.
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            // Explicitly state UI strings (e.g. localised strings)
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

            // etc...

            services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization();
        });
    }
```

However, when I publish this to Azure and visit site, there is no default language engaged, it gives me all the `@SharedLocalizer` variable names. If I then select a language, everything works as intended so I'm left with two questions:

1) When running my site in VS how / where is it setting the default culture?

2) How can I get my site to do this when published via Azure?

I've got this method in my home/index controller but this sets language based on user selection - how is it happening automatically when I'm running it in VS?!

```
    public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(culture);
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = ci;
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not set `DefaultRequestCulture` for `RequestLocalizationOptions`.

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("sv-SE"),
            new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
            new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
        };

        // State what the default culture for your application is. This will be used if no specific culture
        // can be determined for a given request.
        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("sv-SE"),
        // Explicitly state numbers/dates etc.
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        // Explicitly state UI strings (e.g. localised strings)
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
   }
```

Refer to 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.0#localization-middleware

Update:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
        //other middlewares
        app.UseMVc();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't make any difference. Running on visual studio gives me the "en-GB" (which was already happening) and publishing to Azure still gives me the sharedLocaliser variables (i.e. not setting the culture to "en-GB")

Comment: @jamheadart What is your `Configure` method like? `app.UseRequestLocalization` has to be placed before `app.UseMvc` refer to https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/06/22/request-culture-asp-net-core/

Comment: I don't have `app.UseRequestLocalisation` - if I use it then I can't change my culture at all it's always stuck on `en-GB`. I'm using `services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization();` in my Startup

Comment: @jamheadart I update my reply to use `app.UseRequestLocalization`,refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085239/supporteduicultures-doesnt-display-all-the-culture) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57917490/how-to-get-value-of-specific-key-from-resource-file-in-aspnet-core/57921512#57921512)